# Getting error regarding ink node module package

Tags: shopify

```
ERROR Raw mode is not supported on the current process.stdin, which Ink uses
       as input stream by default.
       Read about how to prevent this error on
       https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink/#israwmodesupported

 - Read about how to prevent this error on
   https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink/#israwmodesupported
 -App.handleSetRaw (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/n
  ode             ode_modules/ink/build/components/App.js:56:27)
 - (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/node_modules/ink/
  build/hooks/use-input.js:38:9)
 -invokePassiveEffect (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53
  reate              d/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.devel
                     opment.js:16054:20)
 -Object.invokeGuardedCa (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9
  lbackProd             c53d/node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler
                        .development.js:12101:10)
 -invokeGuardedCal (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/n
  back            ode_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development
                  .js:12292:31)
 -flushPassiveEffec (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/
  sImpl            node_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.developme
nt.js:16141:9)
 -unstable_runWithPr
  iority            (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/
                    node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)
 -runWithPrior (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/node_
  ty          modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:2495
              :10)
 -flushPassiveEff (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/no
  cts            de_modules/react-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.j
                 s:16014:14)
 - (C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/node_modules/reac
  t-reconciler/cjs/react-reconciler.development.js:15891:11)
```

Getting the above error whenever tried to run the below command:
`npm init @shopify/app@latest`

I've updated the node and react as well as the Ink module package.

I've gone through the mentioned link  `https://github.com/vadimdemedes/ink/#israwmodesupported`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: This error occurs because the @shopify/app package uses the ink package, which requires a terminal that supports raw mode. The error message suggests that your terminal does not support raw mode, which means that the ink package cannot be used in this environment.

To fix this issue, run that command in a different terminal that supports raw mode and it's  worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the @shopify/app package uses the ink package, which requires a terminal that supports raw mode.

The error message suggests that your terminal does not support raw mode, which means that the ink package cannot be used in this environment.

***To fix this issue, run that command in windows default cmd by going into search and type cmd then right click and run as administrator. After that run the same commands. It will work.***